# Yii render and renderPartial : Google maps not showing correctly

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, yii, render, google-maps-engine

I am using Yii framework for my application and I have a this code below to initialize and show a **simple google map** with a **layer** I created in **google maps engine.**

```
<script>
    function initialize() {
        initialize2();
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.154136802513362 ,121.26339912414551),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);

      var mapsEngineLayer = new google.maps.visualization.MapsEngineLayer({
        layerId: '07732892464132847854-09507073323105492707',
        map: map
      });

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="width:600px;height:600px;" ></div>
```

But my problem lies in the way it is rendered. When I use the yii **renderPartial()**, this is what this looks like :

[image: RenderPartial]

There is no problem here, the layer is fully shown and the window is complete. But I need to render it using the **render()** method because I need my themes, the navigations and other features of my application basically. But this is what ppears when I use the render() method :

[image: Render]

The tools on the left (zoom and pan buttons are not rendered properly, like clipped),
and the layer doesn't appear, when I zoom in further I get this :

[image: RenderZoom]

The layers are kind of twisted, and plain wrong.

These run on the same code. The only difference is I render one using render() and the one **displaying correctly is the renderPartial()**, but I need to render it using the render() method.

This is really getting weird. Am I missing something with the render() and renderPartial() method? Help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
       <style>
            #map-canvas img
            {
                max-width: none;
            }
        </style>
```

You use bootstrap 2? 
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1552

Comment: Wow! This! Yes sir i'm using bootstrap 2.. Thanks for this! I literally spent half a day solving this.